# In technology contractor employment law what does "lump sum" mean?

Tags: united-states, contract-law, employment

I have a contract that says contractor will be paid X for providing services, is that per pay period, per month, or for the term of the gig?

Comment: It depends on whether it says "for the work" versus "every month". What exactly does the contract say?

Comment: Also, where does the term "lump sum" appear?

Comment: The lump sum is in the apendix. There is no explanation on how often it will be paid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the contract says you will be paid X for providing the services, without further elaboration, it contemplates a single lump sum payment.

Comment: More precisely it means the total payment: the contract or industry practice or law (e.g. building and construction) may mean this will be paid in several progress payments.

Comment: but the AMBIGUITY goes to the person who wrote the contract in contract law, and made sure the company wrote the contract.

Comment: i mean didn't write the contract.

Comment: The contra preferentum rule is not that rigid, and I don't see any ambiguity: a lump sum means a single payment.